# File Output: Writing Data for Multiple Executions?

Tags: python, matplotlib, file-io, output

I have this program. It uses a [Lotka-Volterra ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations) to predict predator and prey populations over a given period of time.

```
import random
import numpy as np
    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate

# note: model parameters are randomly generated
alpha = random.random() * 0.8
beta  = random.random() * 0.003
delta = random.random() * 0.004
gamma = random.random() * 0.8

def f(xy, t):
  '''Lotka-Volterra ODE model'''
  x, y = xy
  dxdt = alpha * x - beta * x * y
  dydt = delta * x * y - gamma * y
  return [dxdt, dydt]

xy0 = [600, 400]
t = np.linspace(0, 50, 250)

xy_t = integrate.odeint(f, xy0, t)

names = ['prey', 'predator']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 4))
axes[0].plot(t, xy_t[:, 0], 'r', label="Prey")
axes[0].plot(t, xy_t[:, 1], 'b', label="Predator")
axes[0].set_xlabel("Time")
axes[0].set_ylabel("Number of animals")
axes[0].legend()
axes[1].plot(xy_t[:,0], xy_t[:, 1], 'k')
axes[1].set_xlabel("Number of prey")
axes[1].set_ylabel("Number of predators")

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Here is what my code produces:

[image: Initial simulation run.]

I would like to be able to...

- Save my matplotlib charts as a pdf file on my computer. I was able to do this by using matplotlib:

```
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
    
    with PdfPages('chart_01.pdf') as pdf:
    
      names = ['prey', 'predator']
    
      fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 4))
      axes[0].plot(t, xy_t[:, 0], 'r', label="Prey")
      axes[0].plot(t, xy_t[:, 1], 'b', label="Predator")
      axes[0].set_xlabel("Time")
      axes[0].set_ylabel("Number of animals")
      axes[0].legend()
      axes[1].plot(xy_t[:,0], xy_t[:, 1], 'k')
      axes[1].set_xlabel("Number of prey")
      axes[1].set_ylabel("Number of predators")
    
      plt.tight_layout()
    
      pdf.savefig(bbox_inches='tight')
```

- Create ***multiple*** charts that result from repeated simulation runs. I don't know how to do this, but here is some pseudocode:

```
    alpha, beta, delta, gamma <-- random

    RUNS = 10 # 10 runs means 10 pdf files

    for i in RUNS:
        data <-- integrate Lotka-Voltera ODE
        filename <-- 'chart_0x.pdf'

        pdf = create_pdf(filename)
        pdf.write_data(data)
```

My idea is that for 10 runs, I will end up having 10 pdfs. The names of these pdfs will be `chart_01.pdf`, `chart_02.pdf`, ... `chart_10.pdf`. I expect that I could do this using the `os` module but I'm worried that I don't know how to do it efficiently.

Has anyone been able to do something like this in the past? I would greatly appreciate your feedback.

CLARIFICATION: I'm not looking for help with ODE-modeling (although I wouldn't mind some tips from anyone who has experience doing that). I brought that in just to provide some context for what I'm trying to do. My question is purely about how to generate multiple files with similar names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf`, you can directly save the image as a pdf using the appropriate extension in the name of the figure. Something like:

```py
for i in range(10):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(data)
    fig.savefig(f"chart_{i}.pdf") 
    fig.clear()
```

If you do not want to make a new figure each time, you can just update the data. This is useful if you have a fairly involved figure preparation

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
myplot, = ax.plot(data)

for i in range(10):
    ndata = data * i # a new data to plot
    myplot.set_ydata(ndata)
    fig.savefig(f"chart_{i}.pdf")
```

Comment: Hi krm! This makes sense. Thank you so much!